# How to test a haml partial with an early return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, haml

I've got a haml partial that should render only for certain people, so it has a `- return unless` at the opening line:

```rb
- return unless user.is_allowed_to_see_this?

stuff here for only them to see
```

Works great in the app, but when testing the view, the rspec `render` helper throws a `no implicit conversion of nil into String` when trying to render the partial rather than returning empty/nil. So to test that the partial is working the test needs to look like:

```rb
  it 'does not show to unallowed user' do
    user = users(:not_allowed)
    expect do
      render('the/haml_partial', user: user)
    end.to raise_error(TypeError)
  end
```

Which feels like it's testing the wrong thing? I feel like the expect should be something like

```rb
expect(rendered).to be_empty
```

I've been digging through the documentation for a while and haven't found anything that seems to work for this. Changing the `- return unless...` to `- if...` makes the `render` call return an empty string rather than an error.  And maybe that's the fix? But I'd like to find a way to keep the early return which I feel is easier to read the intent of as there's no possibility of an `else` to think about.

Comment: Logic in the view. Yucky. I'd say get that logic out into, perhaps, a PORO and make your testing life easier.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty smelly - a partial should not get to decide if it gets rendered or not. That's not its job.

Comment: I'd say it's Rails' fault. It does not offer a way to write this in a DRY way. (cells gem  offers this on the other hand)